# How to concatenate all lists of objects (containing some text) within one big list through the means of stream()

Tags: java, java-stream

I got:
a list of lists of TextInfo objects. Each TextInfo object contains a piece of text and a toString override method to return the text. By the Y value of a TextInfo we can conclude what TextInfo's are on the same line (custom problem)

I want:
a list of strings. Each string is the result of concatenation of all elements of one sublist. And I want to make use of streams as much as possible.

So far:

```
List<String> allLinesByYCoordinate = groupAllTextLineByLineBasedOnY(allTextInfosOnPage);

public static List<String> groupAllTextLineByLineBasedOnY(List<TextInfo> allTextInfo) {
    Map<Object, List<TextInfo>> groupedtextInfosPerLine =  allTextInfo.stream().
                collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getY()));
    List<String> allLines = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Object, List<TextInfo>> groupedtextInfos: groupedtextInfosPerLine.entrySet()) {
        String temp = "";
        for (TextInfo textInfo: groupedtextInfos.getValue()) {
            temp += textInfo;
        }
        allLines.add(temp);
    }
    return allLines;
}
```

You might agree that the method groupAllTextLineByLineBasedOnY looks a bit too oldschool. I 'm trying to execute a concatenation on each of the lists of TextInfo's in the big list, resulting in a list of strings where each string used to be a list of TextInfo's

I'm hoping to find a concise stream() solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's refactor a little at a time.

First, you should never build a string in a loop, as it can be very inefficient; use StringBuilder instead. However, we can instead stream and collect into a string. Also notice here that we using Map.values() instead of calling getValue() inside the loop.

```
public static List<String> groupAllTextLineByLineBasedOnY(List<TextInfo> allTextInfo) {
    Map<Object, List<TextInfo>> groupedtextInfosPerLine = allTextInfo.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getY()));
    List<String> allLines = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<TextInfo> groupedtextInfos: groupedtextInfosPerLine.values()) {
        allLines.add(groupedtextInfos.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining()));
    }
    return allLines;
}
```

In the next refactoring, we can get rid of the intermediate list `allLines` and instead stream the textInfos and collect them into a List:

```
public static List<String> groupAllTextLineByLineBasedOnY(List<TextInfo> allTextInfo) {
    Map<Object, List<TextInfo>> groupedtextInfosPerLine =  allTextInfo.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getY()));

    return groupedtextInfosPerLine.values().stream()
            .map(textInfos -> textInfos.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining()))
            .toList();
}
```

Finally, we can get rid of the groupedtextInfosPerLine variable:

```
public static List<String> groupAllTextLineByLineBasedOnY(List<TextInfo> allTextInfo) {
    return allTextInfo.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TextInfo::getY)).values().stream()
            .map(textInfos -> textInfos.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining()))
            .toList();
}
```

Comment: Wonderful explanation. I will use it (and work to understand it). My biggest problem was working out how to concatenate the strings

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking for a solution like this

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Setup some example data
        List<TextInfo> textInfos = List.of(
                new TextInfo("line 3 a", 3),
                new TextInfo("line 1 a", 1),
                new TextInfo("line 2 a", 2),
                new TextInfo("line 1 b", 1),
                new TextInfo("line 3 b", 3),
                new TextInfo("line 1 c", 1)
        );
        
        // This is the actual answer
        Collection<String> allLines = textInfos.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        TextInfo::getY, // line number as key
                        TextInfo::toString, // convert TextInfo to String
                        (a, b) -> a + b, // Merge TextInfo on the same line
                        TreeMap::new)) // Ensure in order
                .values();

        // You would return allLines from the method
        System.out.println(allLines);
    }

    static class TextInfo {
        String text;
        int y;

        public TextInfo(String text, int y) {
            this.text = text;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getY() { return y; }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return text; }
    }
}
```

If you run the code you print

```
[line 1 aline 1 bline 1 c, line 2 a, line 3 aline 3 b]
```